# Test credit card numbers failing in PayPal REST API vault calls

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use the credit card numbers that I got from https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/, and every card number the I try, I get back "Credit card number is not an accepted test number." when calling https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v3/vault/setup-tokens.  Any ideas what I need to do in order to use these test cards?  Something different in my account?  Or with the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "Test generated card numbers". only works the "Test card numbers" on this link list.

```
https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/
```

[image]

```
371449635398431 American Express
376680816376961 American Express
36259600000004  Diners Club
6304000000000000    Maestro
5063516945005047    Maestro
2223000048400011    Mastercard
4005519200000004    Visa
4012000033330026    Visa
4012000077777777    Visa
4012888888881881    Visa
4217651111111119    Visa
4500600000000061    Visa
4772129056533503    Visa
4915805038587737    Visa
```

The expiry, cvc and name is do not matter.
Only card number is matter.

URL

```
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v3/vault/setup-tokens
```

In Body tab, select `raw` radio button in Postman

```
{
    "payment_source": {
        "card": {
            "number": "4915805038587737",
            "expiry": "2027-01",
            "cvc": "123",
            "name": "Tom Cruise"
        }
    }
}
```

This is result by Postman call
[image]

##### You don't need to get an access token